# MailKit Как получить сообщения папки из папки спам C#

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

Протокол Imap, почта Gmail. Как получать сообщения из общей папки я разобрался, но как работать с папками не могу понять, документация библиотеки пока что для меня сложная.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void DownloadMessages()
    {
        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

            client.Authenticate("username", "password");

            var spamFolder = client.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.Junk);

            spamFolder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            var uids = spamFolder.Search(SearchQuery.All);

            foreach (var uid in uids)
            {
                var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);

                // write the message to a file
                message.WriteTo(string.Format("{0}.eml", uid));
            }

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
```